# Why would HibernateTemplate.merge() complete without exception but not persist data?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I would like to make this question as generic as possible without submitting extensive code and configuration samples so that answer submitters can cover a wide range of possibilities, therefore make it somewhat "academic".

I have two entity classes, `Foo` and `Bar`. They are wired to the persistence store (in my case `PostgreSQL` but I think that shouldn't matter) using `JPA` with `Hibernate` as the provider. They are managed by `FooDao` and `BarDao` respectively and both DAOs extend a `BaseDao` which contains a save method:

```
public T save(T object)
{

    return (T) hibernateTemplate.merge(object);
}
```

which neither DAO overrides (meaning they use the superclass method as is).

The problem is, when I call `myFooDao.save(myFoo)`, it actually persists the objects to the DB but when I call `myBarDao.save(myBar)`, the object is not persisted, **YET NO EXCEPTION IS THROWN**.

All of this runs out of a `Spring` context and both DAOs are [injected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). I should also add both tables have primary keys each tied to its own sequence. While the Bar insertion never actually gets persisted, the associated sequence does get incremented every time, which is odd. So Hibernate does prepare a transaction but getting the next value from the sequence, which increments the sequence, but the new row never shows in the datable.

I am looking to explore some general circumstances under which anomaly can occur. For one, could it be that the configuration is set so that Foo is auto-committed but Bar is not and I should dive into the context configs to find discrepancies? Or could it be that Hibernate thinks the write is successfully committed because the DB engine does not report a failure properly?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate does not necessarily persist your changes after each updating query (`saveOrUpdate`, `merge` for instance).

Its behavior toward persistency is defined by the FlushMode of the Session tied to your HibernateTemplate. The possible FlushModes are described here : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html

By default, an Hibernate Session is setted to `FlushMode.AUTO`. It means that if not absolutly and explictly needed by following queries (to maintain database consistency), no persistent changes are done, except allocation of id by iterating sequences.

It is the result you observed.

To answer your question, if you want to persist your change immediatly after a merge, you will need either :

1) Changing the flush strategy of the Session tied to you HibernateTemplate to "ALWAYS" before merging (or when instanciating the HibernateTemplate).

```
hibernateTemplate.setFlushModeName("FLUSH_ALWAYS");
```

2) Explicitly flushing the Session after merging.

```
hibernateTemplate.flush();
```

But you should also note that HibernateTemplate is a deprecated approach to interact with databases using Hibernate, in particular because HibernateTemplate does not lead people to properly deal with database transactions.

In the first place, your merge used in a transaction would have automatically been persisted when the transaction is committed with `FlushMode.AUTO`.

In a Spring application, you could use a @Transactional annotation, which implicitly executes all the logic included in the annotated method through a transaction.

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Transactional
public void doUpdate(Object myObject) {
  Session hibSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  hibSession.merge(myObject);
}
```

See the complete explanation about Spring transaction management here : http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html (16.5.6 paragraph for @Transactional annotation).

Answer (score 1):

What is the state of your entity at the time of merge? If the entity is in the persistence context (e.g. the session), then an update will occur, if there are any changes made to the object. (if no change, Hibernate will quietly ignore the merge.)

If the entity is not in the persistence context, but it is stored in the DB, then a new row will be inserted, so you'll have duplicate.

Also, please ensure that you are implementing `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods for your entity.